# Execute step or script outside of the Jenkins agent in Declarative Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, declarative

Is there a way to execute step outside of the Jenkins agent?

Suppose that I have following structure of Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Example Stage') {
            agent { someAgent } 
            steps {
                run something ...
                input ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to execute [input](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) outside of an agent to not block it for hours (timeout is not the answer ;))

One of the possible solutions is to execute the logic in separate stages but i'm trying to avoid creating additional ones.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `node` instead of `agent`:

```
pipeline {
    agent none 
    stages {
        stage('Example Stage') {
            steps {
                node( someAgent ) {
                    run something ...
                }
                // outside of any agent
                input ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it runs outside of any agent, where does it run?

Comment: @enanone It runs on the build-in node (former "master").

Comment: shouldn't it run directly in the Jenkins controller, since we did not declare any `node` block?

Comment: @enanone I've used "build-in node" synonymous for "Jenkins controller". More exactly, outside of `node`, the `input` step should run on a [flyweight executor](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-controllers/pipeline-difference-between-flyweight-and-heavyweight-executors), which means it doesn't block a "slot" (heavy-weight executor) on the build-in node.

Comment: Love that resource. Thanks for explaining it!